# Loading only once each tab filter with jquery

Tags: jquery, yui

I have three tabs with a specific filter content per tab. When i click on each tab the specific filter is loaded into the #filterContent div.

The problem is, I want each filter to be loaded only once and showing the good filter per tab.

I'm using the YUI tabview: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/tabview/.

```
var tab0 = tabView.getTab(0);
var tab1 = tabView.getTab(1);
var tab2 = tabView.getTab(2);

tab0.addListener("click", onClickTabToPick);
tab1.addListener("click", onClickTabToSend);
tab2.addListener("click", onClickTabFinished);

var onClickTabToPick = function (e) {
    $.get("/OrderManager/ToPickFilter", function (data) {
        $("#filterContent").html(data);
    });
};

var onClickTabToSend = function (e) {
    $.get("/OrderManager/ToSendFilter", function (data) {
        $("#filterContent").html(data);
    });
};

var onClickTabFinished = function (e) {
    $.get("/OrderManager/FinishedFilter", function (data) {
        $("#filterContent").html(data);
    });
};
```

How I can achieve that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just load data in different containers (filterContent1, filterContent2, filterContent3). You can create these containers with empty innerHTML. Before request you can check $( '#filterContent1' ).html(). If it is empty then make request otherwise just show it.

Also you still can use one container but then you need to store responses from server in some object:

```
var responses = { tab1: null, tab2: null, tab3: null };

var onClickTabToPick = function (e) {
    if ( responses.tab1 == null )
    {
        $.get("/OrderManager/ToPickFilter", function ( data ) {
            responses.tab1 = data;
        });
    }
    $("#filterContent").html( responses.tab1 );
};
```

And for other tabs like for the first.